# Unable to get Raspberry Pi OS to work but DietPi works?

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os

So this is a bit of a weird thing.  I have two Pis though one is a Pi 3B and the other is a Pi 4 with 8GB so I can do some tests.

With the Raspberry Pi OS (tried the following...)

- 32-bit full
- 32-bit lite (buster)
- 32-bit lite (bullseye)
- 64-bit full
- 64-bit lite
- 32-bit lite but via NOOBs (It actually completed the installation from Wifi)

On the Pi 4, the OS shows that it is booting up on the lite versions it is doing the standard boot up sequence log but after a bit it goes blank.

Moved the SD card to the Pi 3 and it starts up succesfully.

Moved the SD card back to the Pi 4 and it still fails the same way.

[Video, please ignore the audio it's not relevant](https://rumble.com/v139h9j-raspberry-pi-os-lite-boot-sequence.html)

---

Since I saw NOOBS working successfully until the Raspberry Pi OS I hypothesized that maybe another OS would work, so I chose DietPi and it did work, the pi starts up and I can connect to it remotely even with a 64-bit architecture image.

With DietPi, i tried to run rpi-eeprom-upgrade and still no luck.

--

I also tried booting up with the recovery and beta recovery images from Raspberry Pi Imager no luck.

I am also using two different MicroSD cards both work on the Pi 3..

Also note, this Pi 4 was working before but I decided to swap the image to 64-bit and it stopped working when I did it.

---

I also tried modifying the config.txt HDMI values (can't remember which ones exactly but I recall)

```
hdmi_safe=1
```

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=1
```

```
hdmi_force_hot_plug=1
```

```
hdmi_increase_power thingy which I set to 9
```

Comment: Are you using the official 5.1V 3.0A power supply on the Pi4?

Comment: yup it came with the canakit raspberry kit. the pi3 is running off my PC.

Comment: Raspberry Pi branded like this?https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/type-c-power-supply/

Comment: *"it is doing the standard boot up sequence log but after a bit it goes blank"* -> You should explain this in better detail as "the standard boot up"  and "after a bit" are both very ambiguous and prone to meaning different things to different people.  Also: Does the screen go completely blank, or is there a blinking underline/cursor upper right?  If not, does the HDMI act like it has no input, or like it has an input (but the screen is blank)?  Most displays do two different things there.

Comment: Added the video.